# Find data at a specified interval

Tags: c#, sql

Database records Like This:

```
===============================

Table
-------------------------------
ID,OtherID, MinNumber,MaxNumber
-------------------------------
1  A       10        100
2  A       101       500
3  A       501       800
-------------------------------
4  B       10        200
5  B       201       550
more ....

-------------------------------
```

Filters (`OtherID=A`,`Number=45` )

How to determine whether the record(Filters) already exists in the table .

*Example*

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE OtherID='A' AND  // code here
```

--- OR ---

C# DataTable:

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable(); (dt's structer and records like Table);
// code here
```

Thanks !

Comment: `[Number] IN (45, 105, 900, ...)`

Comment: Do you want the `Number` to be between `MinNumber` and `MaxNumber`?

Comment: Yes , I have a Add method . data verificate befor execut INSERT operatin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this

```
Declare @int INT
Set @int = 45
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE OtherID='A' AND (@int Between MinNumber And MaxNumber)
```

Comment: It's helpful for me ,Thank you Dhaval .